# Why are Firestore requests hanging in published iOS app but not Expo client?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm building an app with React Native and Expo which uses Firestore as a database. In all my testing in the Expo Client app on iOS my requests to Firestore have been fine, but now I have a build in Apple's TestFlight and all requests to Firestore (reads and writes) are just hanging, leaving loading spinners on the screen (I've added debug text as well so I'm certain it's only Firestore requests).

Since I'm using Expo to build my app, I'm using the Firebase JS SDK as react-native-firebase is not available to use in Expo environments. This could be a problem, but it is the recommended way to use Firebase in the [Expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase/). Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try running in production mode in Expo client, it should make it a lot easier to debug the issue you’re encountering. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/development-mode/

Comment: Did this and got weird errors coming from firebase so I downgraded the version I'm using. Should've thought to switch to production mode earlier!